# Create array of ones in specified order

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a position matrix:

```
positionMatrix = [1 2 3; 1 3 2; 2 1 3];
```

I want a simple implementation (no for loop) that would generates arrays as follow:

```
% there are 3 lines in positionMatrix, so it should generates 3 arrays of ones
array 1 should be [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1] %from positionMatrix 1 2 3 
array 2 should be [1 0 0; 0 0 1; 0 1 0] %from positionMatrix 1 3 2
array 3 should be [0 1 0; 1 0 0; 0 0 1] %from positionMatrix 2 1 3
```

The positionMatrix could be M x N (with M not equal to N).

Comment: Do they have to be 3 arrays, or can they also be 1 big array?

Comment: `for` loops are pretty simple if you ask me.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Well, the 3 arrays are used after that to be multiplied by another array. So I'm getting 3 different results. I suppose they could be in one big array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating the output as a single 3D array

```
 [M N] = size( positionMatrix );
 mx = max(positionMatrix(:)); % max column index
 out = zeros( [N mx M] );
 out( sub2ind( size(out), ...
         repmat( 1:N, [M 1] ),...
         positionMatrix, ...
         repmat( (1:M)', [1 N] ) ) ) = 1;
out(:,:,1) =
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
out(:,:,2) =
 1     0     0
 0     0     1
 0     1     0
out(:,:,3) =
 0     1     0
 1     0     0
 0     0     1
```

if you want each output matrix as a different cell you can use `mat2cell`

```
>> mat2cell( out, N, mx, ones(1,M) )
```

Comment: @m_power why should `mx` by `N-1`? in your example `M=N=mx=3`.

Comment: positionMatrix could be 6x3, `[1 2 3; 1 3 2; 2 1 3; 2 3 1; 3 1 2; 3 2 1]`...oh well i think you are right! I'll check again.

Answer (score 2):

Here I go with `accumarray` again.  Actually, this one is quite intuitive with `accumarray` if you consider that the locations in the output are assigned as follows,

- Column: The values in `positionMatrix`.
- Row: The column in `positionMatrix`.
- Slice:  The row in `positionMatrix`.

If we call the output matrix `map`, this is how to apply `accumarray`:

```
[slices,rows] = ndgrid(1:size(positionMatrix,1),1:size(positionMatrix,2));
map = accumarray([rows(:) positionMatrix(:) slices(:)],ones(1,numel(rows)))
map(:,:,1) =
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
map(:,:,2) =
     1     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     1     0
map(:,:,3) =
     0     1     0
     1     0     0
     0     0     1
```

If needed, you can put the three slices side by side with `map = reshape(map,size(map,1),[],1);`.

Comment: +1 Is there anything that can't be done with `accumarray`? :-)

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done with `ndgrid`:

```
positionMatrixTr = positionMatrix.';
[M N] = size(positionMatrixTr);
L = max(positionMatrixTr(:));
[jj kk] = ndgrid(1:M,1:N);
array = zeros(M,L,N);
array(sub2ind([M L N],jj(:),positionMatrixTr(:),kk(:))) = 1;
```

As the other answers, this gives the result in a 3D array.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it is exactly what you need, but here is something that comes close to the requirements:

```
positionMatrix = [1 2 3; 1 3 2; 2 1 3];

myArray = [positionMatrix == 1, positionMatrix == 2, positionMatrix == 3]
```

This of course assumes that your positionMatrix will grow in the amount of rows, but not (much) in the amount of columns.

Comment: Note that this is just the simplest solution. It can be expanded for an arbitrary amount of columns with things like `repmat` or `kron`. but I'm not sure whether it still qualifies as simple then.